# How to match the the two string or alphanumeric values in apex?

Tags: apex

I have a  query regarding  the matching of two alphanumeric values.
Suppose like i have a first  alphanumeric value say 185,Bakers Street,London and the same second one like 185BakersStreetLondon (without special characters) .  how we can match these in apex code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not ideal but you could use [getLevenshteinDistance](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/Content/apex_methods_system_string.htm#apex_System_String_getLevenshteinDistance) to figure out how close the two Strings are. See the example below:

```
String s = '185,Bakers Street,London';
System.debug(s.getLevenshteinDistance(s)); // Outputs 0
System.debug(s.getLevenshteinDistance('185BakersStreetLondon')); // Outputs 3
System.debug(s.getLevenshteinDistance('123 Fake Avenue, Manchester')); // Outputs 22
```

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how strict you want to be with what you consider to be a match. For example, should the comparison be case-sensitive? But if you just want to remove special characters and then compare the 2 strings, something like this should work.

```
String myStringWithoutSpecial = '185BakersStreetLondon';
String myStringWithSpecial = '185,Bakers Street,London';
String charactersToRemove = '[^a-zA-Z0-9]'; //Remove anything that's not a letter or number
String myStringCleaned = myStringWithSpecial.replaceAll(charactersToRemove,'');
System.assertEquals(myStringWithoutSpecial, myStringCleaned);
```